# using a template with a struct incomplete type error

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    map<string, T> data;
    struct Node* left, * right, * bottom;
    Node(map<string, T> data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        left = right = bottom = NULL;
    }

};


int main()
{
    cout << endl;
   
    map <string, string> test;
    test["walid"] = "walid";
    struct Node* root = new Node(test); #error here
    cout << root->data["walid"];


    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

can someone please tell me why I'm getting incomplete type error? I'm trying to get the node to be created with different map value type depending on the data.

Comment: `Node` is a templated type, and you're not specifying a template parameter.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to quote the full error, please.

Comment: Research _deduction guides_ to see how you might avoid having to specify the type parameter and let it be deduced from the constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

> can someone please tell me why I'm getting incomplete type error?

Because you're attempting to create a pointer to a type that you haven't defined / attempting to create a dynamic object of type that you haven't defined.

You haven't defined a type called `Node`. You've defined a class template called `Node`. You cannot have a `Node*` for the same reason that you cannot have a `std::vector*`. This compiler error explains what is going on:

> ```
> error: template argument required for 'struct Node'
> ```

You can instantiate the template to get a class, which is a type. The angle bracket syntax is used to instantiate templates, and to pass the template arguments. Example:

```
Node<std::string>* root = ...
```

Note that if you let the compiler to deduce the type of the pointer from the initialiser, then the compiler can implicitly deduce the class template arguments (this language feature was introduced in C++17):

```
auto* root = new Node(test);
```

---

P.S. Your example would leak memory if it compiled. Avoid bare owning pointers. Prefer RAII containers and smart pointers instead. Also avoid dynamic allocation when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is not a type, it's a template.  `Node<string>` is the type you are after.

Also, `struct` in a variable declaration is redundant in C++, so change that line to:

```
Node<string>* root = new Node<string>(test);
```

Don't forget to `delete root;` later -- or you could just make `root` a value:

```
Node<string> root{test};
```

Finally, you can optimize several things here with `std::move`, such as:

```
Node(map<string, T> data)
{
    this->data = data;
    left = right = bottom = NULL;
}
```

Using initializer lists and `std::move` you can save a possibly-expensive copy of `data`:

```
Node(map<string, T> d) :
    data{std::move(d)},
    left{nullptr}, right{nullptr}, bottom{nullptr} {}
```

Likewise, since you never use `test` again, you could move that into the constructor argument:

```
Node<string> root{std::move(test)};
```